# Proguard with shrinking and line number

Tags: android, android-proguard

I notice that Google recommends using proguard with shrinking and optimization.
However if we do that, then won't we lose the line number trace in case of reported bugs? The line numbers reported in the error wouldnt match the actual line number of the code so you cant really see where the error occured

Am I missing something? Shouldnt we disable shrinking !
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard has an option to keep the line number info and the mapping for the obfuscated names, so you can retrace it back to your original code.

```
-printmapping out.map

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

More info here:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace

Comment: Yea I undertstand about keeping the liner number. But when you get an error report with line number, it will be based on the generated apk which includes shrinked code. Therefore line 100 in shrink code might be 130 in your orginal code